# Custom Google Analytics events are not visible on the dashboard

Tags: python, google-analytics

I am trying to send custom event (with custom category, action, and value) and for some reason it does not work properly.

I can see new event at "Real-Time -> Events" but I cannot see event category in table below chart.

In addition, I have strange issue with "Behavior -> Events -> Overview" page. Here I can see 0 total events and few hundreds unique events. How it can be possible? I also do not see my custom event category, action, value.

In addition, I cannot find my custom category/action anywhere in GA at all.

Could you please help me - where I can find my custom events?

Here is how I send it to Google Analytics using pyga:

```
from pyga.entities import Visitor, Session, Event
from pyga.requests import Tracker

settings = {
        'ga_tracking_id': 'UA-*********',
        'ga_domain': 'www.********',
    }
    visitor = Visitor()
    visitor.ip_address = "{IP}"
    session = Session()
    tracker = Tracker(settings['ga_tracking_id'], settings['ga_domain'])
    event = Event(category="TEST", action="TEST2")
    tracker.track_event(event, session, visitor)
```

Thank You,

Anton Akhramovich